# How was the method created whose name looks like __ExecuteAsync|1(...)?

Tags: c#, .net

In the image below there are methods names of which are look unusual.

[image]

At the beginning I thought this method was created with expressions. Not least because full name of the method contains word "Expressions".

I checked that and it turned out it's not true. Methods which are produced using expressions, look like [Lightweight Function].

How was the method created whose name looks like **__ExecuteAsync|1(...)** ?

Comment: `async` methods show up like that in the output as well.

Comment: Here is async method https://ibb.co/QDsxJWQ . It looks different.